# Emulate a SMP server with a Linux Cluster?

Tags: cluster, multi-threading, smp

Is it possible to combine a few machines into a cluster and have it appears as a single server? For example, with such a cluster we can run a 32-thread CPU-bound process on 8 quad-core machines.

Are there any existing software that would allow this? The only thing that I'm aware of is [MOSIX](http://www.mosix.org/txt_about.html), but I'm not sure if it works.

I'm understand that it might incur huge performance overhead. However, I still want to try :)

Comment: MOSIX works but not offers SMP (Symmetric multiprocessors) technology, what it is important to have a cluster with shared RAM memory. ScaleMP requires Infiniband interface installed. I guess the both solutions does it not cope with your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but I know a couple of people who use ScaleMP for this purpose.

http://www.scalemp.com/

Any specific reason you want to try this approach?

Answer (score 1):

http://openssi.org/cgi-bin/view?page=openssi.html

Answer (score 1):

*** Disclosure: I am with ScaleMP ***

The short answer to your question is: "Yes, this can be done"

The long answer is:
1. Yes, it can be done.
2. Similar solutions are in production with enterprises and research institutes since 2005.
3. Performance is actually great for workloads that are built to scale on NUMA architectures. See more at http://www.ScaleMP.com/performance.
4. To check if your gear is certified for use with ScaleMP's software, please see http://www.ScaleMP.com/spec